# changing Background color when swiping left or right

Tags: android, swipe

I have `RelativeLayout` which have three `TexView`. I want change Background colour of `RelativeLayout`(only change background all other views inside Relativelayout are same) when swipe left or right.

i tried with `ViewPager` but i dont getting what i wanted.i attached GIF bellow with swipe animation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Here is the code i tried so far:**

```
//some code
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomOnPageChangeListener());
        setUpColors();
}
private void setUpColors(){

        Integer color1 = Color.BLACK;
        Integer color2 = Color.BLUE;
        Integer color3 = Color.GREEN;

        Integer[] colors_temp = {color1, color2, color3};
        colors = colors_temp;

    }
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
    }

    public class CustomOnPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            if(position < (mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount() -1) && position < (colors.length - 1)) {

                mViewPager.setBackgroundColor((Integer) argbEvaluator.evaluate(positionOffset, colors[position], colors[position + 1]));

            } else {

                // the last page color
                mViewPager.setBackgroundColor(colors[colors.length - 1]);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }

    }
```

it changes color of background when swiping but i want a animation like gif attached.currently its fade away color when swiping.

Comment: viewpager must work! but u should put clock in the same layout with viewpager. so viewpager will only contains background color.

Comment: oh i must doing it wrong then. can you provide codes ?Thanks

Comment: please add relevant code of your attempt with viewpager

Comment: i edited question with codes. Thanks

Comment: what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some methods of viewPage and RelativeLayout.

```
switch(mView.getCurrentItem()){
case 0: mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);break;
case 1: mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);break;
case 2: mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);break;
}
```

I hope this will hepl